# How do you handle an Async Response from a Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, asynchronous

I was given the task of creating a web based client for a web service.

I began building it out in c# | .net 4.0 | MVC3 (i can use 4.5 if necessary)

Sounded like a piece of cake until I found out that some of their responses would be asynchronous. This is the flow ... you call a method and they return a response of ack or nack letting you know if your request was valid. Upon an ack response you should expect an async response with the data you requested, which will be sent to a callback url that you provide in your request.

Here are my questions:

1. If I'm building a web app and debugging on localhost:{portnum} how can I give them a callback url.
2. If I have already received a response (ack/nack) and my function finishes firing isn't my connection to the client then over ? How would I then get the data back to the client? My only thought is maybe using something like signalR, but that seems crazy for a customer buy flow.
3. Do I have to treat their response like a webhook? Build something separate that just listens and has no knowledge of the initial request. Just save the data to a db and then have the initial request while loop until there is a record for the unique id sent from the webhook.... oye vey

This really has my brain hurting :-/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Articles, best practices, anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u get solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your service reference, it will generate a *ServiceMethod*Completed delegate. Register an event handler on it to process your data.

Use the *ServiceMethod*_Async() method to call the service.

Answer (score 0):

The way I perceived your question is as follows, though please correct me if I'm wrong about this:

1) You send a request to their endpoint with parameters filled with your data. In addition, you send a:

> callback url that you provide in your request. (quoted from your question)

2) They (hopefully) send an ack for your valid request

3) They eventually send the completed data to your callback url (which you specified).

If this is the flow, it's not all that uncommon especially if the operations on their side may take long periods of time. So let's say that you have some method, we'll call it HandleResponse(data). If you had originally intended to do this synchronously, which rarely happens in  the web world, you would presumably have called HandleResponse( http-webservice-call-tothem );

Instead, since it is they who are initiating the call to HandleResponse, you need to set a route in your web app like /myapp/givemebackmydata/{data} and hook that to HandleResponse. Then, you specify the callbackurl to them as /myapp/givemebackmydata/{data}. Keep in mind without more information I can't say if they will send it as the body of a POST request to your handler or if they will string replace a portion of the url with the actual data, in which case you'd need to substitute {data} in your callback url with whatever placeholder they stipulate in their docs. Do they have docs? If they don't, none of this will help all that much.

Lastly, to get the data back on the client you will likely want some sort of polling loop in your web client, preferably via AJAX. This would run on a setInterval and periodically hit some page on your server that keeps state for whether or not their webservice has called your callback url yet. This is the gnarlier part because you will need to provide state for each request, since multiple people will presumably be waiting for a callback and each callback url hit will map to one of the waiting clients. A GUID may be good for this.

Interesting question, by the way.